# Maintain factor level in stacked plot (ggplot)

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, stacked-chart

Ordering of factor levels in ggplot is a common issue, and there are a number of posts about it (e.g., [Avoid ggplot sorting the x-axis while plotting geom_bar()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20041136/avoid-ggplot-sorting-the-x-axis-while-plotting-geom-bar)).

This may be a duplicate, but I haven't come across this particular situation.

I'm trying to maintain the order of the X-axis variable ("cylinders") in a stacked bar plot. Here's a toy example. I converted the variable below to emphasize the alphabetic ordering on the X axis even though that variable (cylinders) has explicit ordering set earlier in the dataframe as "Four cyl", "Six cyl", and "Eight cyl".

What am I doing wrong?

```
mtcars <- mtcars %>% 
  mutate(cylinders = case_when(cyl == 4 ~ "Four cyl",
                               cyl == 6 ~ "Six cyl",
                               cyl == 8 ~ "Eight cyl"),
         cylinders = reorder(cylinders, cyl, mean)) %>% 
  mutate(engine = case_when(vs == 1 ~ "Manual",
                            vs == 0 ~ "Automatic"))

str(mtcars$cylinders)
levels(mtcars$cylinders)  # [1] "Four cyl"  "Six cyl"   "Eight cyl"
class(mtcars$cylinders)

facet_test <- function(df, gathvar) {

  gath <- enquo(gathvar)

  df %>% 
    select(cylinders, !!gath) %>%
    gather(key, value, -!!gath) %>%
    count(!!gath, key, value) %>%
    group_by(value) %>%
    mutate(perc = round(n/sum(n), 2) * 100) %>%  
    ggplot(aes(x = value, y = perc, fill = !!gath)) +
      geom_bar(stat = "identity")
}

facet_test(df = mtcars, gathvar = engine)
```

[image]

Comment: Run the internals of that function on your data. After the `gather` line, you have 3 columns: `engine`, `key`, and `value`. `value` is where your cylinder information is, but it isn't a factor, so there's no ordering. But I don't see why you need the `gather` anyway—you could have made this plot without it

Comment: As in, take out the `gather` and go straight to `count`, then use `x = cylinders` in your `aes`

Comment: Thanks. The `gather` is there because this is a truncated example of a longer, more complicated function. Any advice on how to make the `value` column retain the factor information?

Comment: Try making `value` a factor and getting the levels by order of appearance in that column (such as using `forcats::fct_inorder`)

Comment: Ok I'll try that. One moment... In the larger function, I'm using facet_wrap, so I have different gathering variables.

Comment: Nope, I hit a wall. I'll keep trying - I'm all ears to any suggestions.

Comment: I think troubleshooting outside `tidyeval` will make things clearer.  As @camille pointed out, after you `gather()` your variable `value` is a character and `ggplot()` then makes it into a factor with default alphanumeric order.  If you want a different order you'll have to manually define it.  In this specific case you'd want to use `mutate(value = factor(value, levels = levels(mtcars$cylinders)) ) ` after `gather()`.  Maybe you need to define an additional variable in your function to be used for setting factor order?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comments and to @alistaire at this post (https://stackoverflow.com/a/39157585/8453014), I was able to arrive at a solution. The problem is that `gather` coerces factors into characters.

**Simple scenario**
As @aosmith suggested, use `mutate(value = factor(value, levels = levels(mtcars$cylinders)) )` after `gather`.

**Complex example with multiple variables**
The important aspects are 1) define factor levels (whether inside or outside of the function) and 2) apply levels to the "value" column.

Here's a more complicated example to show using three variables and applying facet_wrap to see the plots side by side:

```
facet_test <- function(df, gathvar, legend_title) {
  gath <- enquo(gathvar)

# next two lines can go inside or outside of the function
  levels_cyl <- c("Four cyl", "Six cyl", "Eight cyl")
  levels_gears <- c("Three", "Four", "Five")

  df %>% 
    select(cylinders, gears, !!gath) %>%
    gather(key, value, -!!gath) %>%
    count(!!gath, key, value) %>%
    ungroup() %>% 
    mutate(value = factor(value, levels = unique(c(levels_cyl, levels_gears), 
                                                         fromLast = TRUE))) %>% 
    arrange(key, value) %>%  
    ggplot(aes(x = value, y = n, fill = !!gath)) +
      geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
      facet_wrap(~ key, scales = "free_x")
}

facet_test(df = mtcars, gathvar = engine)
```

[[image: correct plot with factor levels in pre-defined order[1]]